# Wann macht die Endung -in keinen Umlaut?

Tags: umlaut, suffix

Die weibliche Endung -in erzeugt normalerweise einen Umlaut:

> Arzt → **Ä**rztin
>   Franzose → Franz**ö**sin

Dies passiert jedoch nicht überall:

> Kunde → K**u**ndin
>   Matrose → Matr**o**sin
>   Verfasser → Verf**a**sserin

Meine erste Hypothese war, dass der Umlaut nur passiert, wenn kein Vokal zwischen betonter Silbe und Endung vorkommt. Das Beispiel *Französin* widerlegt diese Hypothese allerdings.

Gibt es ein allgemeines Muster?

Comment: Ich zweifle an dem *normalerweise* und würde den Anteil auf < 50% schätzen, zumal e und i dafür gar nicht in Frage kommen. Kennt jemand eine Statistik dazu?

Comment: Mit “normalerweise” meine ich natürlich eingeschränkt auf die Situationen, wo die Aussage überhaupt Sinn macht, also wenn der betonte Vokal a, o, u oder au ist.

Answer (score 4):

Ursprünglich trat der Umlaut dann auf, wenn in der folgenden Silbe ein *i* vorkam. Im Englischen wird das Phänomen daher auch als i-Mutation bezeichnet.

Ursprünglich bedeutet hier: Im Althochdeutschen oder noch früheren Sprachformen. Eventuell muss man bis ins Westgermanische oder noch früher zurückgehen.

Das Deutsche hat sich seitdem erheblich verändert und die Umlautbildung ist auch nicht mehr durchgängig produktiv. Daher bezweifle ich, dass sich für das heutige Deutsch ein allgemeingültiges Muster angeben lässt.