# Why is the feminine of Herzog Herzogin and not Herzögin

Tags: umlaut, suffix

Why is the feminine of Herzog Herzogin and not Herzögin (like Gräfin)?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there were any hard and fast rule for it, although I admit that `a` and `u` frequently change to `ä` and `ü` respectively: Rätin, Ärztin, Hündin, Füchsin. Most google search results for *Herzögin* come from 17-19th century documents, so it might be an ancient variant of *Herzogin*.

Comment: Related, in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/wann-macht-die-endung-in-keinen-umlaut

Comment: other 'exceptions': Autorin, Gemahlin, Vogtin (Vögtin also possible), Zypriotin

Answer (score 4):

According to Wiktionary "...umlaut usually occurs in monosyllables, but rarely in polysyllables", which fits the examples given. This is German though, so there are no rules without exceptions.